# How to use a place holder for preparestatement to bind a variable for table name

Tags: java

I have a problem with a prepareStatement. I am trying to build a query to select the count but table names are different  and the code is like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(0) AS CNT FROM ? WHERE STUD_NM <> 'ABC' ";

String tableName;

for (int i = 0; i < studCode.size(); i++) {

    count = 0;

    tableName = "";  

    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstmt.setString( 1 , "S_"+studCode.get(i));

   Syso(pstmt); // 

}
```

Query is prepared like,

```
"SELECT COUNT(0) AS CNT FROM 'S_HUBRECORD' WHERE STUD_NM <> 'ABC'"
```

Why does it append single quotes to table name?

Comment: You may find this replay helpful over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11312274/891092

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to construct your query with string concatenation. `PreparedStatement` is for field values, not for table name. The reason it's wrapping quotes around it is also because you used `setString`.

Answer (score 0):

They treat table name as a string you use type casting may be it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < studCode.size(); i++) {

    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(0) AS CNT FROM "+"S_"+studCode.get(i)+" WHERE STUD_NM <> 'ABC' ";
    count = 0;

    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    Syso(pstmt); // 

}
```

Comment: it works. but can i prepare a query outside of for loop?

Comment: The table name will change for each iteration means how will you move it out?

Comment: if i write code like,                                          String sql = "SELECT COUNT(0) AS CNT FROM "+"S_"? WHERE STUD_NM <> 'ABC' ";                                                   for (int i = 0; i < studCode.size(); i++) {
 
    count = 0;

    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,studCode.size())
    Syso(pstmt); // 

} this prepare query correctly but the problem is that it append single quote to the table name.

Comment: Thats what we are saying. You can't do that. because prepare statement sees ? like a column value so if it string it appends Single Quote. So if you surely want is out side then You can also use search and replace strategy.