# Placeholders not working when using SQL statement in Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

Very first question here so I apologize for any mistakes and imperfections.

Basically there are three files, my main method tech_supportv1, login_controller containing a class used to store a bunch of methods, and login.java, a javabean.
The point is to check if a certain row exists on the tech_support database. To do so I'm trying to use the code below. (db_util and type are classes containing connection data, they are tested and they work).

ISSUE: the data from the main method seems not be pasted into the string in the appropriate placeholders, and an error is returned. (Of course if I manually enter the strings instead of using placeholders, everything works just fine.)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''technicians' WHERE 'techID' LIKE 16' at line 1

I tired to look at the mariaDB docs but all the other syntax provided yields the same results.

So this the main method.

```
public class Tech_support_v1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Start.");

    login bean = new login();

    bean.setTable("technicians");
    bean.setColumn("techID");
    bean.setID(16);

    login_controller.select(bean);

}
```

}

This is the select method (with bean as argument, login is the Javabean class).

```
public static boolean select(login bean) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? LIKE ?";

    ResultSet rs;

    try (
            Connection conn = db_util.getConn(db_type.MYSQL);
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ) {

        stmt.setString(1, bean.getTable());
        stmt.setString(2, bean.getColumn());
        stmt.setInt(3, bean.getID());

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Y");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.err.println("N");
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

I won't include the bean class because it's literally only three variables with the relative set/get methods. Also the database runs with MariaDB, and is MySQL.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code :-)
First, you can't set table or column names with "setString" in a Prepared Statement!
See this Question: [How to use a tablename variable for a java prepared statement insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312155/how-to-use-a-tablename-variable-for-a-java-prepared-statement-insert)
Second, as Daniel Pereira pointed out: You are trying to use a "like" Statement with "setInt"! See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out.

Comment: Just as a side note: if you use "setString" you will always get quoted Strings... so your SQL will look like: `select * from "Table" where "Column" like "%a%"` This is obviously not valid SQL Syntax.

Comment: Allright I got it to work! thanks a lot. Without much altering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing with `LIKE` but you are setting an  `Int`. Change the `LIKE` to `=` and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM :table ";


try (
            Connection conn = db_util.getConn(db_type.MYSQL);
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            )
{
   String query = StringUtils.replace(sql, ":table", bean.getTable());
   stmt.executeQuery(query);
}
```

Comment: You create the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM 'tablename'` which is a syntax error.

Comment: edited my suggestion. Thanks.