# printa a preparedStatement of an SQL query before execute

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using `PreparedStatement` to build my query but i  want to print the final statement after replacing all the variables (replacing the '?') before executing it, apparently the method i need is `PreparedStatement#toString()` like this for example

```
PreparedStatement query = connection.prepareStatement(select ? from ?);
System.out.println("Before : " + query.toString());
query.setString(1, column);
query.setString(2, table);
System.out.println("After : " + query.toString());
```

and the output should be something like this :

```
Before : com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@fa9cf: SELECT ** NOT SPECIFIED ** FROM ** NOT SPECIFIED **
After : com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@fa9cf: SELECT column FROM table
```

but what i get is

```
Before : com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@fa9cf
After : com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@fa9cf
```

i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Use `.asSql()`.

Comment: By the way: you cannot have a ? for the table name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312155/how-to-use-a-tablename-variable-for-a-java-prepared-statement-insert - the table name has to be determined before creating a prepared statement.

Comment: Often the database allows logging of all queries to some degree. Also `ParameterMetaData meta = stmt.getParameterMetaData();` might be useful.

Comment: Are you trying to do this via plain jdbc and you need to log this statement or you are using any framework like spring jpa/hibernate. Depending on usage of framework, you can enable trace logs for sql.

Comment: Oracle with mysql.jdbc?  honestly no idea i'm using someone esle's PC

Comment: and ParameterMetaData meta = stmt.getParameterMetaData();
it gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

> ... and the output should be something like this ...

That is what you *want* the output to be.  Unfortunately (for you) the `toString()` method is not declared by the `PreparedStatement` interface ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)).  So what you appear to be getting is the output from the `toString()` implementation inherited from `Object`.

Is there a way to get the expanded SQL?

There isn't a way to do it portably.  The standard JDBC API does not support this.

However, if you cast the `PreparedStatement` instance to:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` (Connector/J 5.x), or
- `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement` (Connector/J 8.x)

you can then call `asSql()` on the prepared statement to get the expanded SQL.

(Note that for some versions of Connector/J 5.x, the `asSql()` method is declared as `protected` so you can't call it from application code.  This was apparently fixed in 5.1.26.)

Alternatively, from my cursory reading of the code, it looks like calling `toString()` should work as you want it to with Connector/J 8.x, and 5.1.26 or later.

Of course, all of this makes your code dependent on the JDBC driver that you are using.

Another option would be to log the SQL on the database server side.

Comment: asSql() method is not available
and apparently my problem is with the jdbc version or something like that

Comment: Did you cast the prepared statement to `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` first?  Note carefully the package name!!

Comment: But yes is could be a driver version thing; see my updates about 5.1.26 ...