# The variable in the request in the mybatis mapper is not replaced

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

The variable in the request in the mybatis mapper is not replaced.
In the case of "select" queries, everything is fine, but I need to be able to create a table by name.

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Mapper
@Repository
public interface TableMapper {
    @Update("""
        create table if not exists #{name}
        (table_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        update_date varchar(20) NOT NULL)
        """)
    void createTableByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this approach not possible when using mybatis?

In logs:

```
The error occurred while setting parameters
SQL: create table if not exists ? (table_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, update_date varchar(20) NOT NULL)
```

The variable passed to the method is neither empty nor null.

The list of fields in the table itself is not important, only the possibility of creating a table by a given name.

Comment: You cannot use placeholder for a table name [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312274/1261766). You must use `${}` instead. Be sure to sanitize the value to avoid SQL injection. cf. [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-)

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart!!!
What does the choice of #{} or ${} depend on? In the documentation, I saw only #{} everywhere.

Comment: You're welcome :) You should use `#{}` whenever possible because it's safe against SQL injection. `${}` is necessary for table/column names, basically.